# Положил сервак используя exec()

Tags: php, linux, node.js, ubuntu

Написал скрипт, который автоматически будет определять робота и на лету делать для него снапшот страницы. Написал код в php, который проверяет, существует ли снапшот. И если нет, то запускает команду `exec('cd /var/www/developer/; node doSingleSnapshot.js https://www.example.com')`. Открываю страницу, на которой должен выполниться скрипт и замечаю, что сервер начал подтормаживать. Иду в логи и вижу, что каждую секунду в error.log веб-сервера nginx пишется строка с ошибкой 110: Connection timed out. Смотрю в код, что мог сделать не так. Вроде всё в порядке. Пытаюсь обновить страницу, а всё. Сервер лежит. SSH не откликается, как и SFTP. Веб-сервер тоже лежит. Даже ребутнуть сервак через веб-панель хостера(OVH) не могу. Что могло вызвать такое поведение сервера и как мне теперь его поднять? У PHP или NodeJS же должен быть какой-то авто-рубильник?

Увы, код привести не могу, меня выбросило из редактора как только пропал коннект к sftp. Возможно, кто-то сталкивался с подобным или хоть примерно знаком.

**UPD:** сервер поднялся, логи пустые. Добавляю код:

```
if(strpos($ua, 'YandexBot') !== false) {
    $snapshot_name = '/var/www/production/flaut/snapshots' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . 'index.html';
    if(file_exists($snapshot_name)) {
        $now = time();
        $snapshot_created = filemtime($snapshot_name);
        $datediff = $now - $my_date;

        if( round($datediff / (60 * 60 * 24)) > 30) {
            exec('cd /var/www/developer/flaut/dev; node doSingleSnapshot.js ' . urlencode('https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) );
        }
    } else {
        exec('cd /var/www/developer/flaut/dev; node doSingleSnapshot.js ' . urlencode('https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) );
    }
    return require('/var/www/production/flaut/snapshots' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . 'index.html');
}
```

Comment: Почему вы решили, что положил именно exec? LA, df, free -m, ps, htop, access.log смотрели?

Comment: А вообще-то это выглядит как бесконечная рекурсия. Вы открываете `https://www.example.com/`, php-скрипт запускает скачивание `node doSingleSnapshot.js https://www.example.com/` (та же самая страница!), при скачивании естественно запускается php-скрипт, который запускает скачивание самого себя, а это скачивание снова запускает php-скрипт... И так далее до бесконечности, пока на сервере не кончится оперативная память.

Comment: @andreymal да, я опять не подумал головой. php выполняет exec, вызывая снапшот-мейкер. Снапшот-мейкер идёт на страницу и опять выполняет php-скрипт, который опять запускает снапшот-мейкер.